# SQL statement querying result which is within a time range

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I want to do a sql statement which queries by timestamp using javascript.

Here is how i set my timestamp:

```
var startTime = new Date(year, month, day, 0, 0);
var endTime = new Date(year, month, day, 23, 59);
```

My sql statement is:

```
'SELECT * FROM proximate.user WHERE join_timestamp >= $1 ' +
'AND join_timestamp<=$2 ORDER BY user_id ASC';
```

$1 is startTime and $2 is endTime. Given if the startTime is `Sat Dec 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (SGT)` and endTime is `Sat Dec 01 2012 23:59:00 GMT+0800 (SGT)`, the executed statement returns results which include timestamp that is a day before the startTime.

Anyone has any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you receive proper results but forget to convert timestamp column of returned resultset to GMT+8 :  "Sat Dec 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0800" = Fri Nov 30 2012 16:00:00 UTC". Another option - pass dates in UTC. Actually that depends on what you want to get: if you need all users who joined on December 1st GMT+8 you need to convert result set, if you need users who joined on December 1st UTC, pass UTC dates :"Sat Dec 01 2012 00:00:00 UTC"